# Logical negation of a predicate in C++

Tags: c++

I'm following the book Accelerated C++, and to write a function to split a string into a vector of words (separated by space characters), `find_if` is utilized.

```
vector<string> split(const string& str) {
    typedef string::const_iterator iter;
    vector<string> ret;

    iter i = str.begin();
    while (i != str.end()) {
        i = find_if(i, str.end(), not_space);

        iter j = find_if(i, str.end(), space);

        if (i != str.end())
            ret.push_back(string(i, j));
        i = j;
    }
    return ret;
}
```

and the definitions of `space` and `not_space`:

```
bool space(char c) {
    return isspace(c);
}

bool not_space(char c) {
    return !isspace(c);
}
```

Is it necessary to write two separate predicates here, or could one simply pass `!space` in place of `not_space`?

Comment: Your `space` and `not_space` functions are wrong. They must take `unsigned char`.

Comment: @chris How so? It's a templated function accepting "character types", so `char`, `wchar_t`, `unsigned int`, etc. It's perfectly fine to pass `char` only, if it's all you need.

Comment: That's funny - I was pulling these examples straight from the book.

Comment: @Mario, `space` is certainly not templated. Nor is `isspace`. `isspace` requires the argument to be in the range of `unsigned char`, or `EOF`. Using `char` doesn't cut it.

Comment: Well thanks for the help, @chris. I should tell the author.

Comment: @EthanRoseman, Accelerated C++ is pretty old, and is still pretty good, but being that old, I don't think it will accomplish anything.

Comment: @chris is that really so? Okay. I figured I would learn C++11 after reading this book and I'd have mostly everything covered. What would you recommend I switch to?

Comment: @EthanRoseman, We have a list of good [books](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list). As you can see, Accelerated C++ is on there. It's a good book, but as with all books, time hurts. The really good thing about it is that it teaches you to use these standard algorithms and such, and while it can't teach ones that weren't there when it was written, the point still gets across.

Comment: @chris thanks for the link! I'll definitely look into working with a newer book.

Comment: @chris I based my assumption on documentation such as [this one](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/isspace). I'm actually used to `is...()` being for simple `char` only, while using `isw...()` for wide characters.

Comment: @Mario, Ah, yes, that one is, but it also takes an extra argument. The one the OP is using is [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isspace).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot simply use `!space` instead of `not_space` because all you'll be doing in that case is passing `false` to `find_if`. That happens because `space` will decay to a pointer to function, and function pointers are implicitly convertible to `bool`. Applying `!` to the boolean value will always result in `false` (because the function pointer is never going to be `nullptr`).

You can reuse the function `space` by wrapping it in [`std::not1`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/not1), which will negate the result of the predicate passed to it. Unfortunately, it's not as simple as writing `std::not1(space)`, because `not1` requires that the predicate define a nested type named `argument_type`, which your predicate doesn't satisfy.

To convert your function into a predicate usable with `not1`, you must first wrap it in [`std::ptr_fun`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/ptr_fun). So the line in your `split` function becomes:

```
i = find_if(i, str.end(), std::not1(std::ptr_fun(space)));
```

---

With C++11, there's no need for the `not1` and `ptr_fun` shenanigans, just use a lambda expression:

```
i = find_if(i, str.end(), [](char c) {return !space(c);});
```

Comment: Are you sure `!isspace` is `true`? You know `isspace` is not `NULL`?

Comment: @Deduplicator As the post says, function pointers are never going to be null.

Comment: @Deduplicator It's `!space`, the OP's function, not `isspace` from the standard library. But regardless of what function we're talking about, how can the result of taking the address of a function ever be `nullptr`?

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young: THe first sentence currently asserts that `!space` is true, even though `space` designates a fucntion.

Comment: @Deduplicator Oh! I misread your comment. Of course it's always false. Hahaha.

Comment: @Deduplicator Sorry, I didn't understand what you were getting at either.

Answer (score 2):

Just use `std::not1(std::ptr_fun(space))`. `std::not1` is declared in `<functional>`.

(There is also a `std::not2` for use with binary predicates; `std::not1` is for unary predicates.)

Comment: `std::not1` will *not* work. The predicate needs to inherit from `std::unary_function` or provide the typedefs provided by `std::unary_function`. You can get around this by using `std::ptr_fun`.

Answer (score 0):

You can also declare

```
template <bool find_space> bool space(char c) {
    return find_space ^ (!isspace(c));
}
```

and then refer to it as `space<true>` and `space<false>` in the argument to `find_if()`. Much more versatile than `std::not1()`.

Comment: To be honest, I'd prefer `return find_space ? isspace(c) : !isspace(c);` (with appropriately using `std::isspace` and making `c` an `unsigned char`).